# Cannot boot into Ubuntu after crash

Tags: 12.10

After my machine froze, I decided to force shutdown and now I cannot boot into Ubuntu. The boot process passes the Ubuntu 12.10 load screen, it actually shows it for a second then moves to a black screen and hangs there showing the following text. (With "[ OK ]" at the end of each line)

```
*starting virtualbox kernel modules
aned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
*stopping anac(h)ronistic cron
* checking battery state...
*starting CPUS printing spooler/server
* stopping system v level compatibility
*starting
```

That's it. And it hangs on that screen. I can't use my machine at all. I am not running dual boot or a virtual machine. The last thing that happened was, I updated, then I was watching a video on YouTube. When I click on the main launcher on the taskbar, top left, which only showed that icon and the Firefox icon, my machine froze (I couldn't do anything and the video was still playing, didn't see my cursor, no movement at all.)

What can I do?
Luckily I have a Droid to post from which takes two and a half million years for a small post!

Edit: I have 12.10 on a USB stick - if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try booting into safe mode and re-installing virtualbox with either `dpkg` or `apt-get` depending on how you originally installed it with. Sounds like the VBox kernel module is corrupt.